# Make shapes visible if a range contains the shape's name

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

I'm new to the forum and still learning about VBA.

My worksheet has several shapes on it (a map of the United States - each state has its own shape). Small circles placed over the map represent certain cities. I would like to have straight connectors between several of the cities. Although there are many connectors, I want to only show up to three at a time, based on my selection in the range A8:A10. If a certain connector is not named in the range, it should be invisible.

Comment: Post your attempted solution. Try browsing *WorksheetEvents* to start with. Right now, you question is lacking detail and is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement should be:
.Visible = msoTrue or .Visible = msoFalse

```
If yourCondition Then
   Dim oActive As Worksheet     
   Set oActive = ActiveSheet
   oActive.Shapes("CharlotteTruck").Visible = msoTrue
End if
```

---

EDIT:

This is a condition you could use:

```
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A8:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    'condition to run when not clicked in range
 Cancel = True 'This line can be remove if not needed 
    'condition to run if cell in range was clicked
 End If
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm having a little trouble with the condition.  How can I have Excel refer to the range of A8:A10?  I'm a little shaky on the VBA syntax.

Comment: Sorry, one more question.  I have over 30 shapes I'd like to format this way, is it possible to shorten the code by looking up the name of the shape, instead of having coding for each particular shape?

Comment: What condition are you looking for with this range? In other words when do you want the shapes to be visible and when do you want them to be invisible? If one shape is visible are they all visible?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify:  the worksheet has several shapes on it (a map of the United States.  Small circles on the map represent certain cities.  I would like to have straight connectors between several of the cities.  Although there are many connectors, I want to only show up to three at a time, based on my selection in the range A8:A10.  If a certain connector is not named in the range, it should be invisible.

Comment: I added a new edit to show you how you could do the condition. If this answer works for you, please click the green check mark next to this answer to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this the code below. Assumption is that the shapes and your range are on the same sheet.

```
Public Sub Test()

    ActivateShapes ActiveSheet.Range("A8:A10")

End Sub

Public Sub ActivateShapes(rInputRange As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each rCell In rInputRange
        rInputRange.Parent.Shapes(rCell).Visible = msoTrue
    Next rCell

End Sub
```